# Calling payable function with Web3

Tags: web3js

I have some trouble with my code, basically I want to call the payable function in my Smart Contract through Web3.js, here is my code, I'm sure I did something wrong but I can't figure out where.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: When calling the function the MetaMask window pops up with a value of 0 Ether instead of 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have use the address of instance when you are sending the ether to the payable function.
sorry i didn't saw the updated answer.i was typing the answer but i was not able to refreh to your answer.

Comment: Close one, thank you anyway! This would have solved my problem :)

Comment: @Chris bro close this one so that other people don't have to look at this problem as they will see that this is not answered.

Comment: I'm new here, is it now closed now that I marked your answer?

Comment: welcome bro, I am also new here.N ice to meet you, Chris.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. The Web3.js code had to look different